# How to make Jqgrid frozen column word-wrap

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, word-wrap

I am using the latest jqgrid bundle 4.4.5.
I want to make header column word-wrap.
I read the Oleg [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686616/how-can-i-get-jqgrid-frozen-columns-to-work-with-word-wrap-on#8771429) but seem it's not working with the latest jqgrid.

The error messages that appear in firebug is "$grid[0]._complete" is undefined and when is resize the column the error is "this.grid is undefined".

Is there any solution to make it work?

**Edit** : after I change $grid.jqGrid('setFrozenColumns'); to $grid.triggerHandler("jqGridAfterGridComplete");
Now when I resize the column, the frozen div column isn't resize too.

**Note**: I change "this.grid" using local variabel.
var grid = this.grid || this;

Here is the image [link](http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/4369/40896279.jpg).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with version 4.3.2 jqGrid supports [Events](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents#list_of_triggered_events_new_in_v4.3.2) which allows to register *multiple* callbacks (event handler). Old internal callbacks like `_complete` were removed.

Instead of the line in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/WrappedTextAndFrozenColumns.htm)

```
$grid[0].p._complete.call($grid[0]);
```

you can use now

```
$grid.triggerHandler("jqGridAfterGridComplete");
```

**UPDATED**: The current version of jqGrid have a bug in [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.5/js/grid.base.js#L823). It will be used `this` instead of `ts`:

```
if($.isFunction(p.resizeStop)) { p.resizeStop.call(this,nw,idx); }
```

instead of

```
if($.isFunction(p.resizeStop)) { p.resizeStop.call(ts,nw,idx); }
```

The event `jqGridResizeStop` don't have the problem. So I suggest to use it instead:

```
$grid.bind("jqGridResizeStop", function () {
    resizeColumnHeader.call(this);
    fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs.call(this);
    fixGboxHeight.call(this);
});
```

See [the modified demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/WrappedTextAndFrozenColumns2.htm).

**UPDATED 2**: I posted [the bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/wrong-this-in-resizestop-callback/#p28770). I can inform you that [the fix](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/f6b6fd494774f9b9e1f9831a143378da1516d2ed) is already applied in the main code of jqGrid on the github.

Just published version 4.5.0 includes the fix.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. there is a little buggy when resize the column. The frozen header div doesn't resize too.

Comment: Big Thanks Oleg. You save my life :)

Comment: @zenixgrace: You are welcome! I'll post the bug report which I described in my answer later to trirand. I hope it will be fixed in the next version of jqGrid.

Comment: I also found some weird thing about frozen column. I don't know maybe I set the wrong grid config or this is bug.

Comment: @zenixgrace: I think, that it's a bug. I posted [the bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/wrong-this-in-resizestop-callback/#p28770). The most callbacks have DOM of grid as `this`. It' consequent to hold the rule in `resizeStop` and `resizeStart` callbacks.

Comment: Here is the link for the topic (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520874/jqgrid-frozen-column-buggy-or-not)

Comment: @zenixgrace: Sorry, but I don't understand [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16520874/315935). You should describe more clear what is the problem and what is your question. Moreover the code from the question is very bad formatted. To read `colModel` one have to scroll, to scroll and to scroll.

Comment: @zenixgrace: See **UPDATED 2** part of the answer.

Comment: Sorry for my bad code format. I just copied from notepad. Basically the columns didn't appear like how I expected. It should be "NIK,Nama,Divisi,Jam,Tarif,Total,Lain - Lain,Insentif,Total,Potongan Lain - Lain, Total". When the frozen property of rovertime_div is set true, the columns appear like that "NIK,Jam,Tarif,Jam,Tarif,Total,Lain - Lain,Insentif,Total,Potongan Lain - Lain, Total".
Thanks for helping me fixed the bugs.

Comment: @zenixgrace: I still don't understand [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16520874/315935). You can click on "Edit" button under the text of the question and reformat the code and **include more explanation of your problem**. Nobody have interest what code exactly you use really. If you explain the problem on the grid with 2-3 columns you don't need post more as 10 columns which you use in your project. You should think that you post the question *for other people who will read it*.

Comment: I update my question. Hope my question clearer than before. The issue come out when i set useColSpanStyle to true.