# Jqgrid frozen column appear incorrect structure

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm use jqgrid 4.4.5

I have grid configuration like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#listROvertime')
        .jqGrid({           
            //url: 'http://localhost/bison/rovertime/listing',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'post',
            colNames: ["NIK","Nama","Divisi","Jam","Tarif","Total"],
            colModel: [
                {name:"rovertime_nik",index:"rovertime_nik",width:100,
                    frozen:true,
                    key:true,
                    searchoptions:{
                        sopt:["eq","ne","bw","bn","ew","en","cn","nc"]
                    }
                },
                {name:"rovertime_name",index:"rovertime_name",width:260,
                    frozen:true,
                    searchoptions:{
                        sopt:["eq","ne","bw","bn","ew","en","cn","nc"]
                    }
                },
                {name:"rovertime_div",index:"rovertime_div",width:120,
                    frozen:true,
                    search:false
                },
                {name:"rovertime_ocount",index:"rovertime_ocount",width:70,align:"right",
                    formatter:"currency",
                    formatoptions:{thousandsSeparator:","},
                    search:false,
                    sortable:false
                },
                {name:"rovertime_oprice",index:"rovertime_oprice",width:110,align:"right",
                    formatter:"currency",
                    formatoptions:{thousandsSeparator:","},
                    search:false,
                    sortable:false
                },
                {name:"rovertime_over",index:"rovertime_over",width:110,align:"right",
                    formatter:"currency",
                    formatoptions:{thousandsSeparator:","},
                    search:false,
                    sortable:false
                }
            ],
            autowidth: true,            
            caption: 'Laporan Lembur'
        }).jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
            useColSpanStyle: true,
            groupHeaders: [
                {startColumnName: 'rovertime_ocount', numberOfColumns: 3, titleText: '<center>Lembur</center>'}
            ]
        }).jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');
});
```

The result column structure what I expected is "NIK,Nama,Divisi,Jam,Tarif,Total,Lain - Lain,Insentif,Total,Potongan Lain - Lain, Total".
When I set the frozen option to false at the colModel id "rovertime_div", the column structure appears correctly. Otherwise, when I set the frozen option to true, the column structure appears incorrect.

Here's a [picture](http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/7646/48609040.jpg) how the expected results.

**UPDATE 1** : If I set useColSpanStyle: false to column structure appears correctly.

Comment: What exactly is your question ?

Comment: The result column what I expected is "NIK,Nama,Divisi,Jam,Tarif,Total,Lain - Lain,Insentif,Total,Potongan Lain - Lain, Total".

Comment: If you have found the answer for your problem, then i think you should close this question by self answering

Comment: I haven't find the answer. I just describe where the issue come from. Did you try use my grid config code?

Comment: so you mean to say the column names are taken wrongly comparative to what you have mentioned ?

Comment: Can u simulate the same on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @dreamweiver: Yes, that is what i means. Here's the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sKLWa/) of code at jsfiddle

Comment: can we have [chat here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520874/jqgrid-frozen-column-appear-incorrect-structure?noredirect=1#)

Comment: is this what you wanted ? http://jsfiddle.net/sKLWa/2/, i have just changed the `useColSpanStyle: false,` from **true**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set sortable option in your jqgrid `sortable: true,`.

Here is the running [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sKLWa/3/)

Happy coding :)

Comment: yes that is what i want. That is one of the bug I found in jqgrid. I will report to the forum. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @zenixgrace:Well i discovered that many have reported it as error on different forums.you can try posting on jqgrid official site.