# jqGrid Frozen Columns in a Subgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I know that frozen columns does not work if Sub-Grid is enabled from http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:frozencolumns.

My understanding is that frozen does not work in the parent grid but it should work in the **Sub-grid**?

But when I try frozen column in sub grid it does not work? Does it mean frozen columns does not work in both the parent and Sub-grid.

Comment: do you use [Subgrid as Grid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid_as_grid)? Old style [subgrids](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid) don't support frozen columns. Which `datatype` you use in subgrid as grid? Which version of jqGrid you use? You should post the code which you use.

Comment: I am using the latest version as of now jqGrid 4.7.0 . My datatype is json.

Comment: I wrote you about [free jqGrid 4.8.0](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) which are based on jqGrid 4.7.0, but which contains many enhancements shortly described in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) and the readme. I'd recommend you to try it. It's the fork which I will continue to develop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [subgrid as grid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid_as_grid) then jqGrid just creates empty `<div>` in the "subgrid row" where *any* information can be placed. So you can create for example new grid with *any* features in the div. You can create grid with frozen columns of cause.

I created [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SubgridWithLocalGrid_2.htm) for you by modifying the demo from an old answer. The results looks like below

[image]

I marked the header of frozen columns using CSS

```css
.ui-jqgrid .frozen-div .ui-th-column { background: #f0dcdd; color: black; }
```

The code of subgrid is the following

```css
subGrid: true,
subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridId, rowid) {
    var $subgrid = $("<table id='" + subgridId + "_t'></table>");
    $subgrid.appendTo("#" + subgridId);
    $subgrid.jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid).files,
        colNames: ["Name", "Filetype", "col3", "col4"],
        colModel: [
            {name: "name", width: 130, key: true, frozen: true},
            {name: "filetype", width: 130, frozen: true},
            {name: "col3", width: 130},
            {name: "col4", width: 130}
        ],
        height: "100%",
        rowNum: 10,
        sortname: "name",
        shrinkToFit: false,
        autowidth: true,
        idPrefix: "s_" + rowid + "_"
    }).jqGrid("setFrozenColumns");
}
```

I use `shrinkToFit: false` to prevent default shrinking of columns of subgrids together with `autowidth: true` which set the width of the subgrid.

The code works in jqGrid 3.7 or free jqGrid 3.8 which I published recently (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) and [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)), but in case of usage more old versions of jqGrid you can need to trigger `jqGridAfterGridComplete` event (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16628072/315935)).