# JqGrid frozen column

Tags: jqgrid

I've been trying to add frozen column in my jqgrid but i found out there is bug with the last row of my data.

```
.
.
.
    {name:'Code',index:'txt_site_code', hidden:false, align:'center', width:70, frozen:true }

.
.
}); /* end of jqgrid */

    jQuery("#production").jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');
```

Why does the last row does not froze as it should. It will move with the horizontal scroller.
I saw the same 'bug' in trirand.com and trirand.net DEMO on FROZEN COLUMN topic. Any idea on how to solve this..?

thanks..

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the height of the table is not equal to the height of the Div in which it is nested.
You can use jQuery to reassign the height of the table which is frozen.

Note: Use this on GridComplete Function.

```
$(".frozen-bdiv").height(j$(".frozen-bdiv").find("table").height());
```

Answer (score 0):

The column height issue has not been resolved in jqGrid4.8.2.  Using Oleg's solution from '[How to make Jqgrid frozen column word-wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516356/how-to-make-jqgrid-frozen-column-word-wrap/16517257#16517257)' works.  See my code sample.

Comment: Can you include the relevant part of Oleg's solution in your answer?

Comment: He has defined 3 functions: resizeColumnHeader, fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs and fixGboxHeight.  He also has an updated version of the css (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.11.1/css/ui.jqgrid.css) that you can use with JQgrid 4.8 that will resolve the column height issue.

Answer (score 0):

May you can add an onchange method.
This worked for me:

1. Add new height adjustment method:

```
function rowsHeightAdjust(){
    editableRows = $("#jqGrid").find("tr");
    frozenRows = $("#jqGrid_frozen").find("tr");

    for (indexRow=0; indexRow<frozenRows.length;indexRow++){
        if(indexRow > 0 && typeof(editableRows[indexRow]) != 'undefined') {
            $(frozenRows[indexRow]).height($(editableRows[indexRow]).height());
        }
    }
}
```

2. Call the method on some event, eg:

```
//every time we change something on editable fields
$(".editable").change(function(){ rowsHeightAdjust() });
```

Jqgrid creates a new frozen table overlapping the editable one.
This method takes the frozen rows and makes each height match to editable row.
Hope you'll find it helpful.

Comment: Can you explain why you think that this solves the problem?

Answer (score -1):

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <title>test page</title>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

                <!-- A link to a jQuery UI ThemeRoller theme, more than 22 built-in and many more custom -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/testGrid/Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_4_8_2/css/jquery-ui.css" />
                <!-- The link to the CSS that the grid needs -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/testGrid/Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_4_8_2/css/trirand/ui.jqgrid.css" />
            <style type="text/css">
                .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv { overflow-y: scroll;}

                    th.ui-th-column div {
                        /* see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7256972/315935 for details */
                        word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE 5.5+ and CSS3 */
                        white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
                        white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera 4-6 */
                        white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */
                        white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */
                        overflow: hidden;
                        height: auto !important;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                    }
                    .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
                        white-space: normal !important;
                        height: auto;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        padding-top: 2px;
                        padding-bottom: 2px;
                    }
                    .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th.ui-th-column {
                        padding-top: 2px;
                        padding-bottom: 2px;
                    }
                    .ui-jqgrid .frozen-bdiv, .ui-jqgrid .frozen-div {
                        overflow: hidden;
                    }
            </style>    

            </head>
            <body>
                <table id="list"><tr><td /></tr></table>


                <script type="text/ecmascript" src="/testGrid/Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_4_8_2/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/ecmascript" src="/testGrid/Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_4_8_2/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/ecmascript" src="/testGrid/Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_4_8_2/js/trirand/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
                <script type="text/ecmascript">
                    $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
                    $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
                </script>
                <!--script type="text/javascript" src="/testGrid/jqGrid-master/jqGrid-master/js/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script-->
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/testGrid/Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_4_8_2/js/trirand/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                //<![CDATA[
                    /*global $ */
                    /*jslint unparam: true */
                    $(function () {



                        $(document).ready(function () {

                            $grid = $("#list"),
                            resizeColumnHeader = function () {
                                var rowHight, resizeSpanHeight,
                                    // get the header row which contains
                                    headerRow = $(this).closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view")
                                        .find("table.ui-jqgrid-htable>thead>tr.ui-jqgrid-labels");

                                // reset column height
                                headerRow.find("span.ui-jqgrid-resize").each(function () {
                                    this.style.height = '';
                                });

                                // increase the height of the resizing span
                                resizeSpanHeight = 'height: ' + headerRow.height() + 'px !important; cursor: col-resize;';
                                headerRow.find("span.ui-jqgrid-resize").each(function () {
                                    this.style.cssText = resizeSpanHeight;
                                });

                                // set position of the dive with the column header text to the middle
                                rowHight = headerRow.height();
                                headerRow.find("div.ui-jqgrid-sortable").each(function () {
                                    var $div = $(this);
                                    $div.css('top', (rowHight - $div.outerHeight()) / 2 + 'px');
                                });
                            },
                            fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs = function () {
                                var $rows;
                                if (this.grid.fbDiv !== undefined) {
                                    $rows = $('>div>table.ui-jqgrid-btable>tbody>tr', this.grid.bDiv);
                                    $('>table.ui-jqgrid-btable>tbody>tr', this.grid.fbDiv).each(function (i) {
                                        var rowHight = $($rows[i]).height(), rowHightFrozen = $(this).height();
                                        if ($(this).hasClass("jqgrow")) {
                                            $(this).height(rowHight);
                                            rowHightFrozen = $(this).height();
                                            if (rowHight !== rowHightFrozen) {
                                                $(this).height(rowHight + (rowHight - rowHightFrozen));
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                    $(this.grid.fbDiv).height(this.grid.bDiv.clientHeight);
                                    $(this.grid.fbDiv).css($(this.grid.bDiv).position());
                                }
                                if (this.grid.fhDiv !== undefined) {
                                    $rows = $('>div>table.ui-jqgrid-htable>thead>tr', this.grid.hDiv);
                                    $('>table.ui-jqgrid-htable>thead>tr', this.grid.fhDiv).each(function (i) {
                                        var rowHight = $($rows[i]).height(), rowHightFrozen = $(this).height();
                                        $(this).height(rowHight);
                                        rowHightFrozen = $(this).height();
                                        if (rowHight !== rowHightFrozen) {
                                            $(this).height(rowHight + (rowHight - rowHightFrozen));
                                        }
                                    });
                                    $(this.grid.fhDiv).height(this.grid.hDiv.clientHeight);
                                    $(this.grid.fhDiv).css($(this.grid.hDiv).position());
                                }
                            },
                            fixGboxHeight = function () {
                                var gviewHeight = $("#gview_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id)).outerHeight(),
                                    pagerHeight = $(this.p.pager).outerHeight();

                                $("#gbox_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id)).height(gviewHeight + pagerHeight);
                                gviewHeight = $("#gview_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id)).outerHeight();
                                pagerHeight = $(this.p.pager).outerHeight();
                                $("#gbox_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id)).height(gviewHeight + pagerHeight);
                            };


                            // Define the grid
                            $("#list").jqGrid({
                                datatype: 'local',
                                //data: mydata,
                                colNames: ['Country', 'State', 'City', 'Attraction', 'longText', 'Zip code'],
                                colModel: [
                                    { name: 'country', width: 170, align: 'center', frozen: true, cellattr: arrtSetting, title:false},
                                    { name: 'state', width: 180, align: 'center', frozen: true},
                                    { name: 'city', width: 190 },
                                    { name: 'attraction', width: 120 },
                                    { name: 'longText', width: 80000 },
                                    { name: 'zip', index: 'tax', width: 160, align: 'right' }
                                ],
                                cmTemplate: {sortable: false},
                                rowNum: 100,
                                //rowList: [5, 10, 20],
                                //pager: '#pager',
                                gridview: true,
                                hoverrows: false,
                                autoencode: true,
                                ignoreCase: true,
                                viewrecords: true,
                                loadComplete: updateSize,
                                resizeStop: updateSize,
                                //height: '100%', width: null, shrinkToFit: false,
                                height: '80', width: null, shrinkToFit: false,                    
                                caption: 'Grid with rowSpan attributes',
                                beforeSelectRow: function () {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                             $grid = $("#list")
                            jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');
                             $grid.jqGrid('gridResize', {
                            minWidth: 450,
                            stop: function () {
                                fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs.call(this);
                                fixGboxHeight.call(this);
                            },
                            loadComplete: function () {
                                fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs.call(this);
                            }
                        });
                        $grid.bind("jqGridResizeStop", function () {
                            resizeColumnHeader.call(this);
                            fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs.call(this);
                            fixGboxHeight.call(this);
                        });
            //            resizeColumnHeader.call($grid[0]);
            //            //$grid.jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');
            //            $grid.triggerHandler("jqGridAfterGridComplete");
            //            fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs.call($grid[0]);



                            // Data to be sent from various sources and aggregated...
                            var someLongText = "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111098888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww55555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjsdfaddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj4324333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxlllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllpppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd";
                            var mydata = [
                                { country: "USA", state: "Texas",      city: "Houston",       attraction: "NASA",    longText: someLongText,           zip: "77058" , attr: {country: {rowspan: "9"}} },
                                { country: "USA", state: "Texas",      city: "Austin",        attraction: "6th street",         zip: "78704", attr:  {country: {display: "none"}} },
                                { country: "USA", state: "Texas",      city: "Arlinton",      attraction: "Cowboys Stadium",    zip: "76011" , attr: {country: {display: "none"}} },
                                { country: "USA", state: "Texas",      city: "Plano",         attraction: "XYZ place",          zip: "54643" , attr: {country: {display: "none"}} },
                                { country: "USA", state: "Texas",      city: "Dallas",        attraction: "Reunion tower",      zip: "12323" , attr: {country: {display: "none"}} },
                                { country: "USA", state: "California", city: "Los Angeles",   attraction: "Hollywood",          zip: "65456", attr: {country: {display: "none"}} },
                                { country: "USA", state: "California", city: "San Francisco", attraction: "Golden Gate bridge", zip: "94129" , attr: {country: {display: "none"}} },
                                { country: "USA", state: "California", city: "San Diego",     attraction: "See world",          zip: "56653" , attr: {country: {display: "none"}} },
                                { country: "USA", state: "California", city: "Anaheim",       attraction: "Disneyworld",        zip: "92802" , attr: {country: {display: "none"}} }
                            ];

                            // Populate grid
                            for (var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
                                 $("#list").jqGrid('addRowData', "myId_" + i, mydata[i], "last");
                            }

                            resizeColumnHeader.call($grid[0]);
                            //$grid.jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');     Already did this.
                            $grid.triggerHandler("jqGridAfterGridComplete");
                            fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs.call($grid[0]);


                        });



                        arrtSetting = function (rowId, val, rawObject, cm) {                
                            var attr = rawObject.attr[cm.name];
                            var result;
                                if (attr.rowspan) {
                                    result = ' rowspan=' + '"' + 9 + '"';
                                }

                                if (attr.display) {
                                    result = ' style="display:' + attr.display + '"';
                                } 
                                result = result + ' title=" this is the tooltip for '  + rowId + '"';                            
                                return result;
                        };

                        function updateSize(){

                            //getting all lines in two tables by they id
                            var lines = $("tr", this),
                                flines = $("tr", "#"+$(this).attr("id")+"_frozen" );

                            //setting in all frozen lines height equel to grid
                            flines.each(function(i, item){

                                //i%2 check because of border collapse
                                $(item).height( $(lines[i]).innerHeight() - (i%2?1:0) );
                            });
                        };

                    });
                //]]>
                </script>


            </body>
            </html>
```