# Fixing row height of frozen columns jqgrid 4.6

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

I'm trying to fix the row height of frozen columns of JQGrid using [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516356/how-to-make-jqgrid-frozen-column-word-wrap/16517257) article. I have been trying get it to work since couple of days now. I was succeeded up to some extend as grid loads properly but still I'm having issue when re-sizing the column headers.

Only the modification that I have done to the original code is that adding following condition to the fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs function.

> if (this.grid !== undefined) {
>   }

**Steps to Reproduce the Problem:**

1. Load the grid.
2. Try to reduce the width of a column header which allows frozen column's height to be re-sized.

Following is my code:

```
$.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
$.jgrid.useJSON = true;

//<![CDATA[
/*global $ */
/*jslint browser: true, nomen: true */
$(document).ready(function () {
    var budgetType = $('#IntBudgetType').val();
    var budgetExportJQGridDefaults = {
        colNames: ['Item Control No', 'Budget Revision'],
        shrinkToFit: false,
        colModel: [
            {
                name: 'ItemCode', index: 'ItemCode', search: true, width: 190, cellattr: makeCellContentWrap, frozen: true, searchoptions: {
                    sopt: jqGridSearchOperationsFor.String,
                },
                searchrules: jqGridSearchRulesFor.DefaultMandatory
            },
            {
                name: 'BudgetRevision', index: 'BudgetRevision', search: true, width: 120, searchtype: 'number', cellattr: makeCellContentWrap, searchoptions: {
                    sopt: jqGridSearchOperationsFor.Number
                },
                searchrules: jqGridSearchRulesFor.PositiveIntMandatory
            },
        ],
        pager: '#BudgetExportGridPager',
        rowNum: paramFromView.PageSize,
        sortname: paramFromView.SortName,
        sortorder: paramFromView.SortOrder,
        url: paramFromView.Url,
        afterInsertRow: afterInsert,
        loadComplete: function () {
            fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs.call(this);
        }

    };
    //Add filter only if it's available (an attempt to fire searchrules validations when loading)
    if (paramFromView.hasFilter) {
        budgetExportJQGridDefaults = $.extend({}, budgetExportJQGridDefaults, {
            postData: {
                filters: paramFromView.filterStr
            },
            search: paramFromView.hasFilter
        })
    }
    var budgetExportJQGridSearchDefaults = {

    };

    budgetExportJQGridDefaults = $.extend({}, jqGridAppDefaults, budgetExportJQGridDefaults);
    budgetExportJQGridSearchDefaults = $.extend({}, jqGridSearchDefauls, budgetExportJQGridSearchDefaults);

    $('#BudgetExportGrid').jqGrid(budgetExportJQGridDefaults).navGrid('#BudgetExportGridPager', jqGridNavGridDefaultParameters,
    {},
    {},
    {},
    budgetExportJQGridSearchDefaults);

    $("#BudgetExportGrid").jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');

    function ResizeGridAfterScreenResize() {
        $('#BudgetExportGrid').jqGrid('setGridWidth', $('#BudgetExportGrid').parents('.main-content').width() - 2);
    }
    function afterInsert(rowid, rowdata) {
        var val = $(this).jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'Error');;
        if (val != '') {
            $(this).jqGrid('setRowData', rowid, false, 'ui-state-error');
        }

    }

    $(window).resize(function () {
        clearTimeout(this.id);
        this.id = setTimeout(function () {
            ResizeGridAfterScreenResize();
        }, 300);
    });

    //fire 1st time when page has loaded
    ResizeGridAfterScreenResize();

    //});


    'use strict';
    $grid = $("#list"),
    resizeColumnHeader = function () {
        var rowHight, resizeSpanHeight,
            // get the header row which contains
            headerRow = $(this).closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view")
                .find("table.ui-jqgrid-htable>thead>tr.ui-jqgrid-labels");

        // reset column height
        headerRow.find("span.ui-jqgrid-resize").each(function () {
            this.style.height = '';
        });

        // increase the height of the resizing span
        resizeSpanHeight = 'height: ' + headerRow.height() + 'px !important; cursor: col-resize;';
        headerRow.find("span.ui-jqgrid-resize").each(function () {
            this.style.cssText = resizeSpanHeight;
        });

        // set position of the dive with the column header text to the middle
        rowHight = headerRow.height();
        headerRow.find("div.ui-jqgrid-sortable").each(function () {
            var $div = $(this);
            $div.css('top', (rowHight - $div.outerHeight()) / 2 + 'px');
        });
    },
    fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs = function () {
        var $rows;
        if (this.grid !== undefined) {
            if (this.grid.fbDiv !== undefined) {
                $rows = $('>div>table.ui-jqgrid-btable>tbody>tr', this.grid.bDiv);
                $('>table.ui-jqgrid-btable>tbody>tr', this.grid.fbDiv).each(function (i) {
                    var rowHight = $($rows[i]).height(), rowHightFrozen = $(this).height();
                    if ($(this).hasClass("jqgrow")) {
                        $(this).height(rowHight);
                        rowHightFrozen = $(this).height();
                        if (rowHight !== rowHightFrozen) {
                            $(this).height(rowHight + (rowHight - rowHightFrozen));
                        }
                    }
                });
                $(this.grid.fbDiv).height(this.grid.bDiv.clientHeight);
                $(this.grid.fbDiv).css($(this.grid.bDiv).position());
            }

            if (this.grid.fhDiv !== undefined) {
                $rows = $('>div>table.ui-jqgrid-htable>thead>tr', this.grid.hDiv);
                $('>table.ui-jqgrid-htable>thead>tr', this.grid.fhDiv).each(function (i) {
                    var rowHight = $($rows[i]).height(), rowHightFrozen = $(this).height();
                    $(this).height(rowHight);
                    rowHightFrozen = $(this).height();
                    if (rowHight !== rowHightFrozen) {
                        $(this).height(rowHight + (rowHight - rowHightFrozen));
                    }
                });
                $(this.grid.fhDiv).height(this.grid.hDiv.clientHeight);
                $(this.grid.fhDiv).css($(this.grid.hDiv).position());
            }
        }
    },
    fixGboxHeight = function () {
        var gviewHeight = $("#gview_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id)).outerHeight(),
            pagerHeight = $(this.p.pager).outerHeight();

        $("#gbox_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id)).height(gviewHeight + pagerHeight);
        gviewHeight = $("#gview_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id)).outerHeight();
        pagerHeight = $(this.p.pager).outerHeight();
        $("#gbox_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id)).height(gviewHeight + pagerHeight);
    };


    $grid.jqGrid('gridResize', {
        minWidth: 450,
        stop: function () {
            fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs.call(this);
            fixGboxHeight.call(this);
        }
    });
    $grid.bind("jqGridResizeStop", function () {
        resizeColumnHeader.call(this);
        fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs.call(this);
        fixGboxHeight.call(this);
    });
    resizeColumnHeader.call($grid[0]);
    $grid.jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');
    $grid.triggerHandler("jqGridAfterGridComplete");
    fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs.call($grid[0]);
});
//]]>
```

This is how it displays when re-sizing column headers.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [the following demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/WrappedTextAndFrozenColumns2_.htm). Does it have the same problem? If you can reproduce the problem here then please describe the full test case (how the problem could be reproduced step by step).

**UPDATED**: The code which you posted seems be combination of an old code with the code from my demo. The problem exist in the line `$grid = $("#list")`. I use in my demo the grid with `id="list"`, but you use the grid with `id="BudgetExportGrid"`. So `$grid.bind("jqGridResizeStop", ...)` is not work. You should just use the correct id and the problem with resizing should be fixed.

Comment: Tried it, Still the problem seem to exist. However I cannot reproduce the issue on your demo site. It seems the problem is that, first div doesn't get disappeared when re sizing column headers. The strange thing is that when I open the developer tools on the browser, class="frozen-bdiv ui-jqgrid-bdiv" disappears and row heights of the frozen column appears correctly.

Comment: @ecasper: I could help you only if you provide the demo which can be used to reproduce the problem. The only thing which you can try to do is to set `z-index` on `fhDiv`: `$($("#BudgetExportGrid")[0].grid.fhDiv).css("z-index", "1");`. The expression `$("#BudgetExportGrid")[0].grid.fhDiv` is the DOM of div with frozen headers. One should set some large enough "z-index" value. It seems that "1" could be enough.

Comment: That didn't work either. I emailed you the login details to demo site. do you think you can have a look? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ecasper: I debugged the code and have found very simple typing error: see **UPDATED** part of my answer.