# jqGrid - Improper alignment in jqGrid Frozen column header

Tags: jqgrid

when i have included the following style to add wrapping to header text the alignment of frozen columns header is lost.

```css
th.ui-th-column div {
    white-space:normal !important;
    height:auto !important;
    padding:2px;
}
```

How to fix the layout of the frozen column header text?
Below one can see the current results

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that your problem exist because the height of the no-fixed column headers calculated based on `height:auto` is **another** as the height of frozen columns. Both headers *are exist in separate hables of separate divs*. So the height can't be the same if you use `height:auto`.

I think that you should set the height of the frozen headers to fixed `height` value which is the same as the value of non-frozen headers. I described the approach in [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8771429/315935). [The another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16517257/315935) (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/WrappedTextAndFrozenColumns2.htm)) provides small modification of the old suggestion to more recent version of jqGrid.