# jqGrid filtertoolbar is hidden on frozen columns with Group Headers & and Col Span

Tags: jqgrid

I've updated the code from a similar question answered by Oleg

http://stackoverflow.com/q/16516356/315935

The block I entered is as follows
...

```
        $grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar',
                           {   stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, 
                               defaultSearch: 'cn'                                  
                           } )            


        $grid.jqGrid("setGridParam", {sortable: false})  
             .jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
                useColSpanStyle: true, 
                groupHeaders: [{
                   startColumnName: 'amount',
                   numberOfColumns : 3,
                   titleText: '<b>Euro Cols</b>'                       
                }]
             })   

        fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs.call($grid[0]);
```

The result is the The id & client headers have the filter toolbar box hidden
How to show them like the rest of the column headers

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSATM.jpg)

Comment: Please append your question with information which **version** of jqGrid you use and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrd in version <=4.6).

Comment: Sure, jqGrid  4.6.0

Comment: I just appended the code block from above to your demo @ http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/WrappedTextAndFrozenColumns2.htm. The version we use is 4.6 and i see the same issue, i.e filtertoolbar is hidden on frozen cols

Answer (score 0):

The frozenColumns and GroupHeaders are not compatible in version 4.6 and in any of Guriddo version. Here are described the [limitations of frozen columns](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/frozencols/#notes-limitations).

Comment: Thank You, However it looks fine with if useColSpanStyle = false. Maybe there is a workaround, Btw, its a great product