# Frozen Columns in combination with Toolbar Searching, do not work well

Tags: jqgrid

Frozen Columns in combination with Toolbar Searching, do not work well. Please verify this at:  Please help.

Comment: Look at [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8969874/315935).

Answer (score 0):

In your code example you call `filterToolbar` **after** calling of `setFrozenColumns`, but you did nothing what I describe in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8969874/315935). I described the steps which you need do after `toggleToolbar`. The same action you have to do after `filterToolbar`.

A would recommend you better to call `filterToolbar` **before** calling of `setFrozenColumns`.

Comment: @DavidO. It's strange question. I am not owner of the code. I posted many suggestions to trirand. Many from there will be included, but many stay even not unanswered. In the case I in my opinion it is *not* bug. You should just change to order of two line of your code and the problem will be solved.