# Set frozen to first two column of jqGrid using local data. where colModel and colNames are dynamically bound

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

by setting column `frozen : true` in colModel and 
calling

```
jquery(your_jqgridName).jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');
```

It won't work in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have to put capital `Q` in jquery:

```
 jQuery(your_jqgridName).jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');
//^----here
```

> #### [Limitations](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:frozencolumns)
>
> The following limitations tell you when frozen columns can not be
>       set-up
>
> 1. When TreeGrid is enabled
> 2. When SubGrid is enabled
> 3. When cellEdit is enabled
> 4. When inline edit is used - the frozen columns can not be edit.
> 5. When sortable columns are enabled - grid parameter sortable is set to true or is function
> 6. When scroll is set to true or 1
> 7. When Data grouping is enabled
> 8. When footer row (footerrow paremeter) is enabled

Answer (score 0):

From the answer in  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564198/why-doesnt-jqgrid-frozen-column-seem-to-work-with-filter-rows-and-filter-headin/8620574#8620574)

Add this below the set frozen columns.

```
$grid[0].p._complete.call($grid[0]);
```

Where $grid is defined as var $grid = $('#list');.